# Delete array in main memory in cuda c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, cuda

I have the following cuda c++. I am trying to delete the h_c, h_c_Row and  h_c_ColdIndices array using delete function. But the memory is not getting deleted when I see the memory and the value stored in that memory for each array in the debug mode in nsight eclispe.

```
    float *h_c = new float[nnz_c];
    int *h_c_Row = new int[n_k+1];
    int *h_c_ColIndices = new int[nnz_c];
    create_sparse_MY(c,n_k,d,h_c,h_c_Row,h_c_ColIndices, nnz_c);

    // transfer sparse c to device memory
    float *d_sc;  (cudaMalloc(&d_sc, nnz_c * sizeof(float)));
    (cudaMemcpy(d_sc, h_c, (nnz_c) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    int *d_c_ColIndices; (cudaMalloc(&d_c_ColIndices, nnz_c * sizeof(*d_c_ColIndices)));
    (cudaMemcpy(d_c_ColIndices, h_c_ColIndices, (nnz_c) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    int *d_c_RowIndices;  (cudaMalloc(&d_c_RowIndices, (n_k+1) * sizeof(*d_c_RowIndices)));
    (cudaMemcpy(d_c_RowIndices, h_c_Row, (n_k+1) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
     delete[] h_c;
     delete[] h_c_Row;
     delete[] h_c_ColIndices
```

Can someone please help me with it? Is this the right way to delete to arrays in main memory in cuda c++?

Answer (score 1):

Memory being *released* is not the same as memory losing its previous content immediately.

`delete`ing a pointer to an object (or array) calls the objects (plural for arrays) destructor, and makes the memory manager reclaim the memory. In the case of built-in types, the destrcutor does nothing (the memory content doesn't change), but the memory is reclaimed.